# Filtrations generated by cadlag martingales.

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes

Let $(\Omega,P,\mathcal{F})$ be a probability space with filtration $\mathbb{F} = (\mathcal{F}_t), t \in [0,T]$, where $T$ can be finite or infinite.  Let $M$ be a cadlag (local) martingale with respect to $\mathbb{F}$, and let $\mathbb{F}^M$ be the filtration generated by $M$ and then completed with respect to $P$.

Question: Is $\mathbb{F}^M$ a right-continuous filtration?

Some facts:

1. If $X$ is a strong markov process, then the completion of $\mathbb{F}^X$ is right-continuous.  This is in Karatzas and Shreve.
2. A sort of converse: If $M$ is a local martingale in a right continuous and complete filtration, it has a right continuous modification.

One possible idea: A continuous local martingale can be expressed as a time-changed Brownian Motion, which is strong markov.

Comment: It seems to me like an affirmative answer follows directly the "càd" part of càdlàg...perhaps I'm overlooking some nuance?

Comment: Youre saying the completed filtration generated by any cadlag process is right continuous?  If things aren't completed, sets like {M has a local maximum at time t} are in $\mathcal{F}_{t+}$ but not in $\mathcal{F}_t$. 

Comment: Ah, silly me...

Comment: For a brownian motion, those kinds of sets have probability zero.  I'm not sure if that's the only kind of obstruction, but since martingales have the same paths as brownian motion, I had hoped you might be able to say something.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, that is not true. Consider the following, defined on a filtered probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\{\mathcal{F}_t\}\_{t\in[0,T]},\mathbb{P})$.

1. $W$ is a standard Brownian motion.
2. $U$ is an $\mathcal{F}_0$-measurable Bernoulli random variable independent of $W$, with $\mathbb{P}(U=0)=\mathbb{P}(U=1)=1/2$.

Then, set $M_t=UW_t$. This is a continuous martingale. If $\mathcal{F}^M_t$ is its completed natural filtration then $U$ is $\mathcal{F}^M_t$-measurable for all $t > 0$. Then, $U$ is $\mathcal{F}^M_{0+}$-measurable but is not measurable with respect to $\mathcal{F}^M_0$ (which only contains sets with probability 0 and 1). So $\mathcal{F}^M_{0+}\not=\mathcal{F}^M_0$.

Also, this is essentially the same as the example I gave in a [previous answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/43833/a-markov-process-which-is-not-a-strong-markov-process/43841#43841) of a Markov process which is not strong Markov.

---

As another example to show that there is not really any simple way you can modify the question to get an affirmative answer, consider the following; a Brownian motion $W$ and left-continuous, positive, and locally bounded adapted process $H$. Then, $M=H_0+\int H\\,dW$ is a local martingale. Also, $M$ has quadratic variation $[M]=\int H^2_t\\,dt$ which has left-derivative $H^2$ for all $t > 0$. So, $H_t$ is $\mathcal{F}^M_t$-measurable, as is $W_t=\int H^{-1}\\,dM$. In fact, $\mathbb{F}^M$ is the completed natural filtration generated by $W$ and $H$. If $H$ is taken to be independent of $W$, then $\mathbb{F}^M$ will only be right-continuous if $\mathbb{F}^H$ is, and it easy to pick left-continuous processes whose completed natural filtration fails to be right-continuous.

Comment: Thanks.  Maybe i'm being dumb, but can this counterexample be extended to a nonzero starting position?

Comment: @weakstar: I'm not quite sure what you mean. Setting $M_t=UW_t+c$ extends it to a nonzero starting position. If $W$ was started from a nonzero position and you wrote $M=UW_t$, then $U$ would be $\mathcal{F}^M_0$-measurable, so the argument breaks down.

Comment: Right, I meant your second suggestion, for brownian motion starting away from zero.  Just seeing if any affirmative answer can be salvaged.

Comment: @ George Lowther : Hi, could you please recall the version of the Bluementhal 0-1 Law, you are using to justify that sets in $\mathcal{F}_{0^+}^M$ have 0-1 measure. Best Regards

Comment: @The Bridge: I'm not using any such law, nor am I saying that $\mathcal{F}^M\_{0+}$ only has sets with probability 0 or 1 (it doesn't). I was saying that $\mathcal{F}^M\_{0}$ only has sets of measure 0 or 1 (in the first example) because it is generated by a random variable which is identically zero (and then completed).

Comment: @ George Lowther : Got it now, great example !!! by the way this is not important but as I cannot edit my comment, I wanted add that I meant to write $\mathcal{F}_0^M$ not $\mathcal{F}_{0^+}^M$ (for which I do understand why it has sets with non zero-one probability). I was simply missing the fact that $M_0=0$ a.s., so I thought there was some 0-1 law involved and was wondering if this was applicable in the conditions of the problem. Best Regards